# In a procedural macro, how can I check if a string is a valid variable name and not a keyword?

Tags: rust, rust-macros, rust-proc-macros

In a procedural macro, I wish to be able to check a string is a valid variable name and is not a keyword.

`proc_macro2::Ident` will panic if one tries to use an invalid variable name, but it will allow keywords which I do not want to be allowed. It would also be nicer to handle the error with a nice and useful error message before panicking.

Is there some macro or function (in a crate or otherwise) that will check a string obeys the [rules about variable names](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/reference/identifiers.html)? I could probably do it with a regex, but dragons live in regexes.

The use case for this is in handling user input strings, which may include garbage strings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Ident::parse` from the [`syn` crate](https://crates.io/crates/syn). It will fail if the input is a keyword:

```
use syn::{Ident, parse::Parse as _};

let ident = parse_stream.call(Ident::parse)?;
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.rs/syn/1.0.8/syn/struct.Ident.html):

> An identifier constructed with `Ident::new` is permitted to be a Rust keyword, though parsing one through its `Parse` implementation rejects Rust keywords.

Comment: If the string is actually a string (say from a file) rather than a stream, you can do what you need using `syn::parse_str::<syn::Ident>("my_ident_str")?;`